# Visual studio code (Import "Crypto.Util.number" could not be resolved) when i try to run some code for cryptohack

Tags: pycrypto, pycryptodome

I wanted to start solving puzzles and stuff on cryptohack because one of my university classes requires it and i want to use the python library pycryptodome but even after installing it i get the error :Import "Crypto.Util.number" could not be resolved.

i've tried a few time to uninstall and reinstall the library but it doesn't seem to fix it and whenever i try to do 'pip3 install --upgrade pycrypto' i get these errors at the bottom

"
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycrypto
Running setup.py clean for pycrypto
Failed to build pycrypto"

any recommendations for fixing it will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall `pycrypto` and `pycryptodome`. Try to uninstall both so that conflicting packages are removed.

```
pip uninstall pycrypto
pup uninstall pycryptodome
```

Then install `pycryptodome`.

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

Comment: i tried this it didn't really change anything i uninstalled and reinstalled it a bunch of times. and i managed to fix it with the very simple solution of going to pycharm for my python project and completely uninstalled vscode from my pc. can't deal with that program its only good for C/C++ and even then i doubt notepad++ couldn't do the job better.Anywhose thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @Tetoros21Bill - Another simple solution is to create a virtual environment. Then install pycryptodome. https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html Make sure you understand the difference between pycrypto and pycryptodome. Once you do, you will understand your import problem. You also have another problem. You do not have valid C build tools installed. How to fix that depends on your operating system. When you are ready create a new question for that problem.